# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"? Запятую поставил учитель!

Tags: запятые, как

В парке было очень тихо, было слышно, как падают золотые листья.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно нужна! Правильно он поставил её. Эта запятая отделяет придаточное предложение от предшествующей части. Вторая часть большого предложения образует СПП.